# Hooking into hidden surface removal/backface culling to swap textures in WebGL?

Tags: algorithm, 3d, rendering, webgl

I want to swap textures on the faces of a rotating cube whenever they face away from the camera; detecting these faces is not entirely equivalent to, but very similar to hidden surface removal. Is it possible to hook into the builtin backface culling function/depth buffer to determine this, particularly if I want to extend this to more complex polygons?

There is a simple solution using dot products described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338719/box-backface-culling) but I am wondering if it's possible to hook into existing functions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can hook into internal WebGL processing but even if it's possible it wouldn't be the best way for you. Doing this would need your GPU to switch current texture on triangle-by-triangle basis, messing up with internal caches, etc. and in general - our GPUs don't like `if` commands.

You can however render your mesh with first texture and face culling enabled, then set your cull face direction to opposite and render your mesh with 2nd texture. This way you'll get different texture on front- and back-facing triangles.

As I think of it - if you have a `correct` mesh that uses face culling you shouldn't get any difference, because you'll never see a back-face, so the only ways it could be useful is for transparent meshes or not-so-correctly closed ones, like billboards. If you want to use this approach with transparency then you'll need to carefully pick the correct rendering order.